# brew install graphviz - [#<Dependency: "python" []>, #<Options: []>] cannot be installed as binary package and must be built from source

Tags: python, homebrew, graphviz

When I try to write `brew install graphviz` in the terminal the error is

```
Error: The following formula
  [#Dependency: "python" []>, #<Options: []>]
cannot be installed as binary package and must be built from source.
Install the Command Line Tools:
  xcode-select --install
```

I tried already `xcode-select --install` with the result:

> "xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools"

Comment: So did you try installing the command line tools as suggested?

Comment: Please insert your steps so we can know what you did.

Comment: I did not do anything, except for "brew install graphviz", then i tried " xcode-select --install" with the result "xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have installed the xcode-select --install, you can proceed again with the brew install graphviz succesfully. Try it